# Grabbing image by specific suffix from mediawiki API queries

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm querying the yugipedia media wiki to collect card images. I have no issues querying for the main image for each title query:

https://yugipedia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Dark_Magician&format=json&prop=pageimages&piprop=original

Will give me the main card image link for the `Dark Magician` page. However, the image I am trying to get to is the `Legacy of Duelists` image inside the image gallery related to Dark Magician. These cards all have the same suffix of `LD-EN-VG.png` so in the case of Dark Magician the file is named `DarkMagician-LD-EN-VG.png`

Is there any way to tailor the api query to only provide files with that specific suffix?

I can list all of the image urls in the gallery with:

https://yugipedia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Card%20Gallery:Dark%20Magician&format=json&generator=images&gimlimit=500&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url

But I'm stuck at filtering out just the `LD-EN-VG.png` query result. Trying to avoid using Python or Javascript to apply a regex to the queried JSON object and instead get it done with the API query itself.

Comment: I could not locate any image with the suffix 'LD-EN-VG,png' in the article 'Card Gallery:Dark Magician'.  You wil get pageid as -1 in such cases for the [query url](https://yugipedia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Dark_Magician-LD-EN-VG.png&format=json&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the name including the suffix for titles parameter.

I could not locate any image with the suffix 'LD-EN-VG,png' in the article 'Card Gallery:Dark Magician'.  You wil get pageid as -1 in such cases for the [query url](https://yugipedia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Dark_Magician-LD-EN-VG.png&format=json&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url). For an [available file query](https://yugipedia.com/api.php?action=query&titles=File:DarkMagician-LOB-NA-UR-UE.jpg&format=json&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url), you will get the proper result.